# melt pandas dataframe and divide two rows based on column

Tags: pandas, melt

I have a dataFrame of the form:

```
                   0
college     gender  
Engineering F      117
            M      2240
```

and I want to change it to:

```
college       M:F
Engineering   19:1
```

where M:F represents the ratio of Male to Female.

Is there anyway to do this with pandas without iterating over all rows?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and then divide:

```
df = df.unstack()[0]
#same as
#df = df[0].unstack()
```

```
df['M:F'] = df['M'] / df['F']
#same as
#df['M:F']  = df['M'].div(df['F'])
```

---

```
print (df)
                        0
college      gender      
Engineering  F        117
             M       2240
Engineering1 F        117
             M       2240
```

```
df = df.unstack()[0]
df['M:F']  = df['M'].div(df['F'])
print (df)
gender          F     M        M:F
college                           
Engineering   117  2240  19.145299
Engineering1  117  2240  19.145299

print (df[['M:F']])
gender              M:F
college                
Engineering   19.145299
Engineering1  19.145299
```